# Qlikview ignore selection in text box (object)

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, set-analysis, qlik-expression

I have a text box that contains an expression, however i dont want it to be affected by the selections in the list boxes.

```
=SUM(IF( (date(Monthname(C_DATE),'MMM-YY')) >=(AddMonths(Today(),-12)),1,0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `{1}` prefix in the expression will ignore all selections from listboxes (or other).

```
=Sum({1} If((Date(Monthname(C_DATE), 'MMM-YY')) >=(AddMonths(Today(),-12)), 1, 0))
```